# Make a unique dynamic list in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a question about making a unique list that is depended of the range from the original list.

I now have this formula:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(Tabel15[Equipment];MATCH(0;AANTAL.ALS(Analyses!$O$2:O7;Tabel15[Equipment]);0));"")}
```

This formula gives me a list of unique values that are in `Tabel15-Equipment`. To update the unique list I have to manually adapt the range of $O$2:O7 when a new value is filled in. Is it possible to make the range $O$2:O7 dynamic? So that I don't have to adapt the range of this new table?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I do now know how is your data, of what kind of data you store i Column O, but what about using `O:O` instead of `$O$2:O7`? Anyways, I suggest you to post an example data, because it can help users to make a proper answer for you.

Comment: have you tried giving that range of cells a name? usually works across sheets as well...

Comment: Why adapt it? Simply copy that formula down a suitable number of rows. Blanks will occur in rows beyond the number of returns.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns You're missing the point of the construction. The first cell within the range passed needs to have an absolute row reference. The point is that, for the first instance of the formula, we have `$O$2:O2`, which becomes, in succesive rows as the formula is dragged down, `$O$2:O3`, `$O$2:O4`, etc.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns yes i made a mistake in my question and you're right about the problem. But do you or anyone else know how to adapt this range so that the list is always complete? Maybe a dataset could change from 5 values to a 100 and i would like to update it automatically. My excel vba knowledge is not so good so i prefer a formula if possible. Sorry for  my bad English but I'm from the Netherlands

Comment: @XORLX I understand your point and you are right. That's why I asked OP post data example.

Comment: Just trying to give ideas... Maybe you can put the list values ($O$2:O2) in a new table. Then your formula could be Tabel16[MyAwesomeList] and it would adapt automatically...

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MAX((Analyses!$O:$O<>"")*ROW(Analyses!!$O:$O)))
```

to get the last row of column O of Analyses sheet and replace number number 7!

with this you get the range:

`INDIRECT("Analyses!A1:A"&SUMPRODUCT(MAX((Analyses!$A:$A<>"")*ROW(Analyses!$A:$A))))`

try (i not sure) to get the full formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Tabel15[Equipment];MATCH(0;AANTAL.ALS("Analyses!$O$2:O" & SUMPRODUCT(MAX((Analyses!$A:$A<>"")*ROW(Analyses!$A:$A))));Tabel15[Equipment]);0));"")
```

Comment: See my comment to FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns in the OP's post. This proposal is flawed.

Comment: @XOR LX i have a very bad connection and i can not see other post.it s took long to reload!

Comment: Then I'll repeat it here: You're missing the point of the construction. The first cell within the range passed needs to have an absolute row reference. The point is that, for the first instance of the formula, we have $O$2:O2, which becomes, in succesive rows as the formula is dragged down, $O$2:O3, $O$2:O4, etc.

Comment: @Error 1004 i understand what you are trying to say but could you add this to my original formula? I can't get it to work properly. Is there a way i can attach a file or picture here?

Comment: @Error 1004 I got your formula to work but how do i make it work so i don't need to adapt the range manually by selecting the table and drag it down?

Comment: @Mischa Urlings i provide a solution and you devote it,i provide another solution and you want to give you full explanation?i believe that you have to work a bit.

Comment: @Error 1004 I think my problem is a bit different then you think. The formula you give is good when i insert this in a specific cell. But when dragging the formula down the part of $O$2:O7 adapts itself to a higher number until i stop dragging down. Maybe i can adapt the table range  to the number i calculated via your formula with the sumproduct?